# Inserting many rows into SQL Server 2000 via SqlCommand in .NET - NOT updating the sysindexes (rows) properly

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am calling an insert method about 2000 times in a row (through a foreach loop in C#). Everything inserts into the table just fine, but the `sysindexes` `rowcnt` for that table does not update properly.

Let's say that I call the insert method 2100 times in that foreach loop, the `rowcnt` from `sysindexes` table for `<table>` now says 2085. But if I do a `select count(1) from <table>` I get the proper number of records (2100).

The number that I get from the `rowcnt` usually varies, but it always around the correct number of rows.

We are running SQL Server 2000 - yes I know, it is 15 years old and that might have something to do with it. I did see that `sysindexes` for SQL Server 2000 can be a little shaky, and they recommend using other views rather than that one if you have a never version, but we don't.

The really silly part is that if I run that insert method just one time, and insert just one record, it updates the `sysindexes` rows & `rowcnt` to the proper number. Isn't that something?

The code below shows the method that is being called all those times in a row. Any help is greatly appreciated. I make the insert string and then I send it to the method to run the query - yes I know how to use `Command.Parameters` and I should not hard code values into a string, but I replicated another process without doing it properly just to test it and it gives me the same results/problem that I am asking about.

> Insert Statement is as follows: INSERT INTO (item_no, totalTransactions, compileDate) VALUES('test', 1.0, 20140820)

```
private void btnTestTableInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rowsAffected = 0;
    String bigInsert = "";

    bigInsert += "INSERT INTO iminvtrx_sql_i(item_no, totalTransactions, compileDate) ";

    for (int i = 0; i < 2100; i++)
    {
        rowsAffected += addToDatabase(i);
    }

    MessageBox.Show("There were " + rowsAffected.ToString() + " added to the table!");
}


private int addToDatabase(int count)
{
    int rowsAffected = 0;
    string insertString = "";

    using (SqlConnection connection = finder.getConnectionFor("data_01"))
    {
        SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

        insertString = "BEGIN TRANSACTION INSERT INTO iminvtrx_sql_i(item_no, totalTransactions, compileDate) VALUES('test', 1.0, @increment) COMMIT TRANSACTION";
        command.CommandText = insertString;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@increment", count);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.InnerException.ToString());
        }
    }

    return rowsAffected;
}
```

Comment: I think maybe this is related to statistics.  Google sp_updatestats, I'm not sure, but I think this is related somehow.  Maybe it can be used to refresh the value.

Comment: get rid of  this line `int rowsAffected = 0;` replace this line `rowsAffected += command.ExecuteNonQuery();` with this line 
`int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();` also can yo show the query that you are using..? what happens if you replace that Insert Text Query and create a Stored Procedure..?

Comment: @AaronLS -  MSDN says that sp_updatestats applies to SQL Server 2008 and above..  But I did forget to mention that 'DBCC UPDATEUSAGE(0, '<tableName>') WITH COUNT_ROWS' does update the count properly as well.  However I was hoping to find out why it is even being thrown off in the first place.. Thank you!

Comment: @DJKRAZE - 'INSERT INTO <tableName>(item_no, totalTransactions, compileDate) VALUES('test', 1.0, 20140820)' - that is the insert statement that I am using - not exact values but you get the gist of it..

Comment: @DJKRAZE - And I am not familiar with a Stored Procedure. I looked at how to do it and I think I get it but I will need to try it out to see if I really get it.

Comment: have you thought about putting an explicit `Commit` at the end of the Insert statement..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE - I did do that, then it complained that I did not start a transaction.  So I put BEGIN TRANSACTION at the beginning and it ran, but the count shows 2083 rather than the 2100 rows that are in the table now.

Comment: could you have inserted duplicates can you delete the table rows and try it again.. just to make sure your query is truly not working as you may think.. do you have a timestamp field on that table..? if so write a quick delete statement to delete records that were inserted today.. then start over and see if the totals match after the insert.

Comment: can you show the `foreach` code you are talking about perhaps that's where something could be mucking up

Comment: @DJKRAZE - this is funny, because I did exactly as you said...but now instead of 2083, the count says 2113.  Mind you, the actual count of rows in the table is 2100 on the dot. Then I deleted all rows again - and now the row count says 13.  There has to be some sort of connection there..

Comment: well could it be that Sql Server 2000 is the issue most of us on here are probably on much higher / updated versions have you checked to make sure you don't have any Constraints on the table any foreignkey violations, Triggers etc.. what about Indexes is that table indexed properly..? Please show how `private int addToDatabase(string insertString)` Method is being called

Comment: @DJKRAZE - I accidentally showed the wrong method the first time - so I just updated the code and added the method with the foreach loop. Hopefully that helps.  My bad I had the method overloaded and it looked the same.

Comment: look at the code I just updated for you also why are you hard coding the value of `2100` can you explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you mention is expected.  The row count stored in system tables is not guaranteed to be 100% accurate and can be corrected with DBCC UPDATEUSAGE (which sp_spaceused optionally invokes when the updateusage option is specified).  The only way to get a transactionally consistent rowcount in any version of SQL Server is with `SELECT COUNT`.

The rowcount stored in the DMVs in SQL 2005 and later versions tends to be more accurate.

Comment: I suppose I am just going to have to live with it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

can you change the code to have a separate counter it almost looks like the `+=` assignment is returning and or tracking the count incorrectly just break it apart like this

```
private void btnTestTableInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rowsAffected = 0;
    String bigInsert = "";
    bigInsert = "INSERT INTO iminvtrx_sql_i(item_no, totalTransactions, compileDate)";

    for (int i = 0; i < 2100; i++)
    {
       rowsAffected += addToDatabase(i);
    }

    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("There were {0} added to the table!", rowsAffected.ToString()));
}


private int addToDatabase(int count)
{
    int rowsAffected = 0;
    string insertString = "";
    SqlConnection connection = finder.getConnectionFor("data_01");
    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

    insertString = "BEGIN TRANSACTION INSERT INTO iminvtrx_sql_i(item_no, totalTransactions, compileDate) VALUES('test', 1.0, @increment) COMMIT TRANSACTION";
    command.CommandText = insertString;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@increment", count);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        rowsAffected++;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.InnerException.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection != null)
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

    return rowsAffected;
}
```

> you do not need this `+=` in this method private int addToDatabase(int count)
>   I changed it to only use rowsAffected

I would suggest reading up on what `+= , +-, etc...Operator Overloads are and when to use them`

Comment: I don't understand what actually changed here - I see the `totLoopCnt` variable, but where is it actually being used?  The reasoning for me hard coding 2100 in is because this is just a test method and by doing this action this many times it replicates the problem.  I could put in 1500 and it would still probably replicate it as well.

Comment: look closely, I removed your += in the rowsAffected  in the addToDataBase Method I also changed your ShowMessage to display values based on param vs using `+` everywhere

Comment: I changed this line to ` bigInsert = "INSERT INTO iminvtrx_sql_i(item_no, totalTransactions, compileDate)";` you had `+=` for assigning an empty string when you don't need to

Comment: I actually do know all about those operators.. I did it like that accidentally out of habit of doing a similar action all the time..but due to the problems I have been having today, and because I am only using this for testing purposes - I have not taken the 3 seconds to fix it.

Comment: well using += does increments as well as adding to strings depending on how you use it .. so like I said try the fix I added for you

Comment: when you get more familiar with coding also wrap your SqlCommand and SqlConnection in a `using(){}` so that objects can be disposed automatically

Comment: I had to change one thing for it to run - the `rowsAffected` variable had to be declared outside of the `try` block in order for the return statement to see that it had a value.. but just as before, the code ran and I get a count of `2087` now rather than 2100 or 2083. Like I said it varies all the time.  I am guessing it has to do with the ancient SQL Server that is causing the problem.

Comment: I agree.. do you have a DBA on staff

Comment: I know that we have a guy that we go to for database backing our databases up and other stuff, but I do not believe he is a DBA in the sense that you may know the term. Asking him most definitely could not hurt though.

Comment: And thank you for letting me know about the `using(){}` statement!  I just looked it up, makes perfect sense. Much appreciated.

Comment: not a problem I appreciate your patience and willingness to try as well as learn new things